Button to download file and redirect to new page
How do I enable my button to download and redirect to a new page? I have tried many code combination but it just downloads and does not redirect
<div class="banner">
    <h3>Download your file:<br> {{ filename }}</h3>
    <div>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <form action="{% url 'download_pdf' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button onclick="openTab()" class="btn btn-primary w-20" id="myBtn" tabindex="4">Download PDF
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
function openTab() {
window.open('home');
}
</script>


You could try something like this to ensure both downloading the file and redirecting to a new page are achieved. The button click that already triggers download and then you can register a brief delay using JavaScript to redirect to your desired page:
<div class="banner">
    <h3>Download your file:<br> {{ filename }}</h3>
    <div>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <form id="downloadForm" action="{% url 'download_pdf' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-20" id="myBtn" tabindex="4" onclick="downloadAndRedirect()">Download PDF</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function downloadAndRedirect() {
    // Submit the form to trigger the download
    document.getElementById('downloadForm').submit();
    
    // Redirect after a short delay to allow the download to start
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = 'home'; // Change 'home' to your desired redirect URL
    }, 1000); // Adjust the delay time as necessary
}
</script>


using default submit behavior will redirect the page which will cancel out setTimeout()

works, thank you

@MichaelJoseph it worked? then my comment is wrong, sorry everyone
